# How to manually specify checkpoint path in PyTorchLightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Currently I am using TensorBoardLogger for all my needs and it's perfect, but i do not like how it handles checkpoint naming. I'd prefer to be able to specify the filename and the folder where to put the checkpoint manually, how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible thanks to the ModelCheckPoint callback:

```
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath="best_models",
    filename='{epoch}-{val_loss:.2f}-{other_metric:.2f}'
)
trainer = Trainer(callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

will create a checkpoint in the directory `best_models/epoch=2-val_loss=0.02-other_metric=0.03.ckpt` for example